# Where can I add js libraries in reactJs project?

Tags: reactjs

I want add stomp.js file to reactjs project. Where should I add this file? In angular are two options: index.html or angular.json. How about react?

JavaScript code from other project:

```
function connect() {
    //connect to stomp where stomp endpoint is exposed
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/greeting");
    ws = Stomp.over(socket);

    ws.connect({}, function(frame) {
        ws.subscribe("/user/queue/errors", function(message) {
            alert("Error " + message.body);
        });

        ws.subscribe("/user/queue/reply", function(message) {
            showGreeting(message.body);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert("STOMP error " + error);
    });
}
```

Current project structure:
[image: project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - install the library (using npm or yarn)

2 - import them in any file you need

There is **no** need to define them in a central namespace or something *(indeed `package.json` will act like that)*;

---

for example `stomp.js`:

1 - `npm i @stomp/stompjs`

2 - now using it's [`Client`](https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/Client.html#info) in `app.js`

```
import { Client } from "@stomp/stompjs";

function App() {
  const stompClient = new Client({});

  return (
    <main> 
      
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add external js files through the `import` keyword in ES6. Basically you should do:

```js
import exportedFunction from "<path-to-file>/stomp"
```

This should work, assuming that "stomp.js" is a file in your project structure and not a package to be installed (in this case you should install it using the package manager first before importing)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import